# Python Turtle fill the triangle with color?

Tags: python, colors, turtle-graphics

I am currently using the `turtle.goto` cords from a text file. I have the triangle drawn and everything but I don't know how to fill the triangle.

Answer (score 2):

You are ending fill after every new coordinate. You need to call `t.begin_fill()` before your `for` loop and call `t.end_fill()` after the last coordinate, otherwise you are just filling in your single line with each iteration.

Comment: If this resolved your issue, can you mark it as accepted? And if it did not, can I help you further?