# How can I fill in my Shape in Python with Turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I would like to fill in my Shape that I have created with the turtle module in python.
I have figured out the outlines and the Turtle itself, but I don`t know how to color in the finished shape. This is my code so far:

````
    trtl.fillcolor("green")
    trtl.shape("turtle")
    
    if currentdepth == depth:
        trtl.forward(length)
    else:
        currentlength = length/3.0
        trtl.pencolor("Blue")
        koch_segment(trtl, currentlength,currentdepth + 1)
        trtl.left(60)
        trtl.pencolor("Red")
        koch_segment(trtl, currentlength, currentdepth + 1)
        trtl.right(120)
        trtl.pencolor("Green")
        koch_segment(trtl, currentlength, currentdepth + 1)
        trtl.left(60)
        trtl.pencolor("Orange")
        koch_segment(trtl, currentlength, currentdepth + 1)



    wn = turtle.Screen()
    wx = wn.window_width() * .5
    wh = wn.window_height() * .5
    base_lgth = 2.0 / math.sqrt(3.0) * wh       # is the base length dependant on the screen size
    myturtle = turtle.Turtle()
    myturtle.speed(0.5 * (depth + 9))           # value between 1 and 10 (fast)
    myturtle.penup()
    myturtle.setposition((-wx / 2, -wh / 2))    # start in the lower left quadrant middle point
    myturtle.pendown()
    myturtle.left(60)

    return myturtle, base_lgth```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Turtle fill the triangle with color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160995/python-turtle-fill-the-triangle-with-color)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are trying to fill a recursive drawing function, we probably need to do the fill commands around the initial call to that function.  Working with the code you posted, it would be something like:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

DEPTH = 4
LENGTH = 300

def koch_segment(turtle, length, currentdepth):

    if currentdepth == 1:
        turtle.forward(length)
    else:
        currentlength = length/3

        turtle.pencolor('blue')
        koch_segment(turtle, currentlength, currentdepth - 1)
        turtle.left(60)

        turtle.pencolor('red')
        koch_segment(turtle, currentlength, currentdepth - 1)
        turtle.right(120)

        turtle.pencolor('green')
        koch_segment(turtle, currentlength, currentdepth - 1)
        turtle.left(60)

        turtle.pencolor('orange')
        koch_segment(turtle, currentlength, currentdepth - 1)

screen = Screen()
wx = screen.window_width()/2
wh = screen.window_height()/2

base_length = wh * 2 / 3.0**0.5  # the base length is dependent on the screen size

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.fillcolor('grey')  # some color we haven't used as a pen color
turtle.shape('turtle')
turtle.speed('fastest')

turtle.penup()
turtle.setposition(-wx/2, -wh/2)  # start in the lower left quadrant middle point
turtle.pendown()
turtle.left(60)

turtle.begin_fill()
koch_segment(turtle, LENGTH, DEPTH)
turtle.end_fill()

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

I've made slight changes to your program, like counting down on the recursion depth instead of up, to make it simpler for me to work with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `begin_fill()`, draw your shape and then `end_fill()`:

```
from turtle import *

color('red', 'yellow')

begin_fill()

# drawing a square
while True:
    forward(200)
    left(90)
    if abs(pos()) < 1:
        break

end_fill()

done()
```

In your code it would look something like this:

```
trtl.begin_fill()
trtl.fillcolor("green")
trtl.shape("turtle")

if currentdepth == depth:
    trtl.forward(length)
else:
    currentlength = length/3.0
    trtl.pencolor("Blue")
    koch_segment(trtl, currentlength,currentdepth + 1)
    trtl.left(60)
    trtl.pencolor("Red")
    koch_segment(trtl, currentlength, currentdepth + 1)
    trtl.right(120)
    trtl.pencolor("Green")
    koch_segment(trtl, currentlength, currentdepth + 1)
    trtl.left(60)
    trtl.pencolor("Orange")
    koch_segment(trtl, currentlength, currentdepth + 1)



wn = turtle.Screen()
wx = wn.window_width() * .5
wh = wn.window_height() * .5
base_lgth = 2.0 / math.sqrt(3.0) * wh       # is the base length dependant on the screen size
myturtle = turtle.Turtle()
myturtle.speed(0.5 * (depth + 9))           # value between 1 and 10 (fast)
myturtle.penup()
myturtle.setposition((-wx / 2, -wh / 2))    # start in the lower left quadrant middle point
myturtle.pendown()
myturtle.left(60)
trtl.end_fill()

return myturtle, base_lgth
```

Comment: It does not work like this:

Comment: i have added begin_fill() right above the "if" and the end_fill() underneath the lastkoch_segment. I have also added done()

Comment: Where do I need to write it in my code excactly?

Comment: assuming "trtl" is a turtle.Turtle() variable, try: trtl.begin_fill(), trtl.end_fill() and turtle.done()

Comment: I edited my answer to show how it would look like in your code

Comment: Thank you so much, but I still can`t figure out how it is supposed to work.

Comment: Can you post your full code so I can explain it better? If it is too long you can put it on GitHub